# Unable to start minikube - Initialization failed

Tags: docker, macos, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to run minikube start but kept facing this error.

Output when I run `minikube start`:

```bash
  minikube v1.32.0 on Darwin 14.2.1 (arm64)
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Updating the running docker "minikube" container ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.28.3 on Docker 24.0.7 ...-
  initialization failed, will try again: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH="/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.28.3:$PATH" kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,NumCPU,Mem,SystemVerification,FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables": Process exited with status 3
stdout:

stderr:
apiServer.certSANs: Invalid value: "": altname is not a valid IP address, DNS label or a DNS label with subdomain wildcards: a lowercase RFC 1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*'); a wildcard DNS-1123 subdomain must start with '*.', followed by a valid DNS subdomain, which must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.' and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. '*.example.com', regex used for validation is '\*\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher


  Error starting cluster: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH="/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.28.3:$PATH" kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,NumCPU,Mem,SystemVerification,FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables": Process exited with status 3
stdout:

stderr:
apiServer.certSANs: Invalid value: "": altname is not a valid IP address, DNS label or a DNS label with subdomain wildcards: a lowercase RFC 1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*'); a wildcard DNS-1123 subdomain must start with '*.', followed by a valid DNS subdomain, which must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.' and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. '*.example.com', regex used for validation is '\*\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher


╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                           │
│      If the above advice does not help, please let us know:                             │
│      https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose                           │
│                                                                                           │
│    Please run `minikube logs --file=logs.txt` and attach logs.txt to the GitHub issue.    │
│                                                                                           │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

❌  Exiting due to K8S_INVALID_CERT_HOSTNAME: wait: /bin/bash -c "sudo env PATH="/var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.28.3:$PATH" kubeadm init --config /var/tmp/minikube/kubeadm.yaml  --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube,DirAvailable--var-lib-minikube-etcd,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml,FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml,Port-10250,Swap,NumCPU,Mem,SystemVerification,FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables": Process exited with status 3
stdout:

stderr:
apiServer.certSANs: Invalid value: "": altname is not a valid IP address, DNS label or a DNS label with subdomain wildcards: a lowercase RFC 1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*'); a wildcard DNS-1123 subdomain must start with '*.', followed by a valid DNS subdomain, which must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.' and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. '*.example.com', regex used for validation is '\*\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

  Suggestion: The certificate hostname provided appears to be invalid (may be a minikube bug, try 'minikube delete')
  Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/9175

╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                           │
│      If the above advice does not help, please let us know:                             │
│      https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose                           │
│                                                                                           │
│    Please run `minikube logs --file=logs.txt` and attach logs.txt to the GitHub issue.    │
│                                                                                           │
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Output of `kubectl version`:

```bash
Client Version: v1.29.0
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Environment:

- macOS Sonoma Version 14.2.1
- Macbook Pro Apple Silicon
- Minikube version v1.32.0
- Kubectl v1.29.0
- Docker:

```bash
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.35+desktop.5
 Version:           24.0.7
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.10
 Git commit:        afdd53b
 Built:             Thu Oct 26 09:04:20 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           desktop-linux

Server: Docker Desktop 4.26.1 (131620)
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.7
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.10
  Git commit:       311b9ff
  Built:            Thu Oct 26 09:08:15 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.25
  GitCommit:        d8f198a4ed8892c764191ef7b3b06d8a2eeb5c7f
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.10
  GitCommit:        v1.1.10-0-g18a0cb0
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

What I've tried so far:

- Reinstall Docker
- Reinstall minikube/kubectl
- Have also removed the ~/.minikube and ~/.kube folder
- Tried downloading via brew, as well as binary download